# Move key/value in object array to other array by matched item

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have two arrays with objects containing countries and their country code.
One of the arrays have the countries in English and also have key with the country's isoCode. It looks like:

```
[{
 "name": "Denmark",
 "dialCode": "+45",
 "isoCode": "DK",
},
{
 "name": "Germany",
 "dialCode": "+49",
 "isoCode": "DE",
}]
```

The other array has the country names in Danish and the dialcode but without the isoCode.

```
[{
 "name": "Danmark",
 "dialCode": "+45",
},
{
 "name": "Tyskland",
 "dialCode": "+49",
}]
```

Now I want to move/copy the isoCode from the English array to the Danish, matched by the dialCode.
But I am a little lost on how to do this.

I have a matching with this

```
let result = this.dkList.filter(country1 => this.countryList.some(country2 => country2.dialCode === country1.dialCode.replace('00 ', '+').trim()))
```

My expected result should be

```
[{
    "name": "Danmark",
    "dialCode": "+45",
    "isoCode": "DK"
  },
  {
    "name": "Tyskland",
    "dialCode": "+49",
    "isoCode": "DE"
  }
]
```

Comment: Your data is not an array. Its an object

Comment: @Nitheesh "two arrays with objects"...

Comment: Are you also able to provide an example of your expected result with the above data?

Comment: @NickParsons -  I have edited my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.filter()` method is used to remove items from an array, which isn't what you're looking to do here, instead, you're looking to map (ie: transform) your data.

You can first create a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) called `isoLookup` from your first array that creates keys based. on the `dialCode` and values based on the `isoCode` in your array. You can then you this Map to obtain the ISO code using a `dialCode`. Once you have created the Map lookup, you can use `.map()` on your second arr2 to map your objects to new objects with an `isoCode` property, that holds a value obtained from the Map lookup:

```js
const arr1 = [{ "name": "Denmark", "dialCode": "+45", "isoCode": "DK", }, { "name": "Germany", "dialCode": "+49", "isoCode": "DE", }];
const arr2 = [{ "name": "Danmark", "dialCode": "+45", }, { "name": "Tyskland", "dialCode": "+49", }];

const isoLookup = new Map(arr1.map(obj => [obj.dialCode, obj.isoCode]));
const res = arr2.map(obj => ({...obj, isoCode: isoLookup.get(obj.dialCode)}));
console.log(res);
```

Creating a Map to serve as a lookup allows your code to scale nicely, as apposed to performing the search through `arr1` for each iteration of your `.map()` method.

Comment: Thanks! Will look into this! I am using filter to remove countries from the english array that can't be found in the danish array, like for example "Antarctica".

Comment: @MortenHagh ah, got you, I mistook it for code that wasn't working. All good then, `.map()` for this should be what is needed

Comment: Got your code to work perfectly with mine! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just go through all array elements, compare their dialCodes and copy isoCodes to danish version.

```
const en = [...]; // array with english data
const den = [...]; // array with danish data

// it will work if en.length = den.length
for (let i = 0; i < en.length; i++) {
  if (den[i].dialCode === en[i].dialCode) { // compare en & den dial codes
    den[i].isoCode = en[i].isoCode;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var en = []
var den = []
den.forEach(eni => {
    en.forEach(deni => {
        if (eni.dialcode == deni.dialcode) {
            den.dialcode = en.dialcode
        }
    })
})
```

now you should have the array in var den

Answer (score 0):

Because both lists contain `dialCode`: with [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) you can create a hash from `arr1` based on the `dialCode` property and finally get the result out of [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Map) `arr2` list

Code:

```js
const arr1 = [{name: 'Denmark',dialCode: '+45',isoCode: 'DK',},{name: 'Germany',dialCode: '+49',isoCode: 'DE'}]
const arr2 = [{name: ' Danmark',dialCode: '+45',},{name: 'Tyskland',dialCode: '+49'}]

const hash = arr1.reduce((a, c) => ((a[c.dialCode] = c.isoCode), a), {});
const restult = arr2.map(c => ({ ...c, isoCode: hash[c.dialCode] }));

console.log(restult);
```

Answer (score 0):

One line solution, if don't mind

```js
const arr1 = [{ "name": "Denmark", "dialCode": "+45", "isoCode": "DK", }, { "name": "Germany", "dialCode": "+49", "isoCode": "DE", }];
const arr2 = [{ "name": "Danmark", "dialCode": "+45", }, { "name": "Tyskland", "dialCode": "+49", }];

result = arr1.map(({ dialCode, isoCode }) => ({ name: arr2.find((o) => dialCode === o.dialCode).name, dialCode, isoCode }));

console.log(result);
```